# SQL Table "Pointer"?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, variables, sql-server-2000

Using SQl Server 2000 I have a stored procedure that joins 2 tables and then returns the data. I want this sp to be able to do this for whatever table name I pass into it, otherwise I'll have the exact same code with the exception of the table name 20 or so times in a giant if statement. Basically, how do I use a variable to point to a table, or is that allowed? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL, start here [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) to learn how to do it correctly so that nobody drops your tables or does anything else possible with `SQL Injection`

Answer (score 0):

Try building the SELECT as a string and then calling EXEC and passing the string.

e.g.

```
declare @sql varchar(500)
set @sql = 'select whatever from ' + @tableName
exec @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

One proc to do anything is usually a bad bad idea. 20 possible tables I might need to go to depending on the circumstances almost always indicates a database design that is bad. Read the article Denis posted on the curses and blessings of dynamic SQL.

Comment: There are certain columns in every table that are consistent, and that is what I am pulling. Would it be better to have 20 if statements?

Comment: If I had five columns that were the same in 20 tables, I would pull them out to a separate parent table. That's what I mean about your database design being bad.

Comment: Possibly, but it wouldn't work with how I'm displaying the data and updating it.